# Community user id interpreted by absolute value in search

Tags: bug, search, community-user

On every use profile page the search bar on the top of the page already contains `user:<id>` text to simplify search for post of the currently visible user. But this doesn’t work correctly for the [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user:

> [image: community]

Instead of searching for posts owned by Community user I’ve got Jeff Atwood posts:

> [image: atwood]

In this case minus sign was just ignored and instead of (-1, i.e. Community user), the (+1, i.e. Jeff Atwood) is used. Same happened for any other negative id for the “user:” option in the search box.

Comment: ... are there posts that are posted by "Community" user?

Comment: @Somewhat there is only one on MSE (you can see it on the profile page). On other sites there can be more (or less).

Comment: Also doesn't work for [user:..0 (0 or less)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A..0) -- worse is that the URL adds quotes so that becomes "user:..0", which returns results omitting the periods; but when typed directly into the 'search results searchbar' (not the one at the top of the webpage, the second one) it doesn't add the quotes and makes the correct query (without quotes) but incorrectly returns zero results.

Comment: To view all the activities of the **[Community User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity)** you can visit directly (which oddly leaves "user:-1" on the search bar, but re-searching using that result in the bar doesn't work). The webpage ***does*** take a few seconds to load, because currently there are over 
147,701 Actions.

Comment: If you like that one, try [Stack Overflow's Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=all) - with over a million actions ([*after* culling...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377547/accessing-communitys-profile-all-actions-tab-timeout/378126#378126)), it spins for a noticeable bit before showing up.